# What is the best practice to grow a very large binary file rapidly?

Tags: java, clojure

My Java application deals with large binary data files using memory mapped file (MappedByteBuffer, FileChannel and RandomAccessFile). It often needs to grow the binary file - my current approach is to re-map the file with a larger region.

It works, however there are two problems

1. Grow takes more and more time as the file becomes larger.
2. If grow is conducted very rapidly (E.G. in a while(true) loop), JVM will hang forever after the re-map operation is done for about 30,000+ times.

What are the alternative approaches, and what is the best way to do this?

Also I cannot figure out why the second problem occurs. Please also suggest your opinion on that problem.

Thank you!

Current code for growing a file, if it helps:

```
(set! data (.map ^FileChannel data-fc FileChannel$MapMode/READ_WRITE
                         0 (+ (.limit ^MappedByteBuffer data) (+ DOC-HDR room))))
```

Comment: Have you considered not growing in fixed chunks but doubling the size every time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to grow your file in larger chunks.  Use a doubling each time you remap, like a [dynamic array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array), so that the cost for growing is an amortized constant.

I don't know why the remap hangs after 30,000 times, that seems odd.  But you should be able to get away with a *lot* less than 30,000 remaps if you use the scheme I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The JVM doesn't clean up memory mappings even if you call the cleaner explicitly. Thank you @EJP for the correction.

If you create 32,000 of these they could be all in existence at once. BTW: I suspect you might be hitting some 15-bit limit.

The only solution for this is; don't create so many mapping.  You can map an entire disk 4 TB disk with less than 4K mapping.

I wouldn't create a mapping less than 16 to 128 MB if you know the usage will grow and I would consider up to 1 GB per mapping.  The reason you can do this with little cost is that the main memory and disk space will not be allocated until you actually use the pages. i.e. the main memory usage grows 4 KB at a time.

The only reason I wouldn't create a 2 GB mapping is Java doesn't support this due to an Integer.MAX_VALUE size limit :( If you have 2 GB or more you have to create multiple mappings.

Comment: "The JVM cleans up old memory mappings on a GC" Is this true all of a sudden? They've been telling us for years that memory mapped files are never GC'd at all unless you call the sun.whatever thing, for the same reason there is no public unmap() API: there is no agreed time when it is safe to release the mapped memory.

Comment: @EJP You are right, I just checked and all the code is there to support unmapping via Cleaners which is created for a MappedByteBuffer etc but the "unmapper" is always `null` for memory mapped file which I didn't expect. The Cleaner only de-allocates direct memory buffer on a GC. This means that calling it explicitly won't help either. You could call unmap via reflection but I suspect you are right that this is very dangerous.

Comment: thank you very much for the info, i never realized that mmap has troubles with GC. I'll avoid growing the file too often

Comment: @HowardGuo If you have an `ArrayList<MappedByteBuffer>` you never need to resize a region, just keep adding MappedByteBuffers.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can afford an exponential growth on the file like doubling, or any other constant multiplier, you need to consider whether you really need a `MappedByteBuffer` at all, considering their limitations (unable to grow the file, no GC, etc). I personally would either be reviewing the problem or else using a `RandomAccessFile` in "rw" mode, probably with a virtual-array layer over the top of it.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I am sticking with mmap at the moment and try to avoid remap too often